# listView in android: app unfortunately stopped working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to make a app using list view and database .But every time I want to compile it my app shows message

> " app unfortunately stopped working "

My code are below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    FixtureAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseClass db=new DatabaseClass(this);

   db.addFixture(new Fixture("Bangladesh","Australis","Melborne","22 feb 2014"));
  db.addFixture(new Fixture("India","Pakistan","Sydney","15 feb 2014"));


  ArrayList<Fixture> fx= db.getAllContacts();

  adapter = new FixtureAdapter(this,
          fx);

          ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         dataList.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

adapter calss:

```
public class FixtureAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fixture> {
Activity context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Fixture> data=new ArrayList<Fixture>();
/*public FixtureAdapter(Context context , int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Fixture> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.context = (Activity)context;
this.data = data;
}*/

public FixtureAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Fixture> data) {
    super(context, R.layout.fixture, data);

    this.context = (Activity)context;
    this.data = data;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fixture,null);
      TextView teamone=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.teamOneName);
      TextView teamtwo=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.teamTwoName);
      TextView vs=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.vs);
      TextView venue=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.venue);
      TextView date=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);

      ImageView teamoneimg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamOneImg);
      ImageView teamtwoimg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamTwoImg);


      Fixture f=data.get(position);

      teamone.setText(f.getTeamOne());
      teamtwo.setText(f.getTeamTwo());
      vs.setText("Vs");
      venue.setText(f.getVenue());
      date.setText(f.getDateInt());


      if(teamone.getText().toString()=="Bangladesh")
      {
          teamoneimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb);
      }
      else
      {
          teamoneimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
          teamtwoimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      }
    }
    return row;

}



}
```

Xml files:

main.xml
    `

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>`
```

fixture.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"

     >

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <!-- first team and name -->

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/teamOneImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamOneName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="team 1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- vs  -->

     <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vs" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- second team and name -->

      <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Team two" />

    </LinearLayout>

       <!-- venue and date  -->

      <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="2" >
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/venue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Venue" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Date and time" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have check the database class it has no problem .I think the problem is with the adapter class But I fail to identify it.

Comment: What do you mean by "...getting error every time i want to compile it ."? What is the error?

Comment: .But my app shows" app unfortunately stopped working " message every time i want to compile it

Comment: attach logcat exeption message please

Comment: please share error log

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a compile-time error is different to a run-time error. The message you get about your app having "stoped working" is a ru-time error and has nothing to do with compiling it.

Second, in your `getView(...)` adapter method, you are returning null unless the `convertView` is null.

Change the `getView(..)` method of your adapter as follows (also note the correct way to compare strings in Java - I've commented the code)...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fixture,null);
    }

    TextView teamone=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.teamOneName);
    TextView teamtwo=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.teamTwoName);
    TextView vs=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.vs);
    TextView venue=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.venue);
    TextView date=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);

    ImageView teamoneimg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamOneImg);
    ImageView teamtwoimg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamTwoImg);

    Fixture f=data.get(position);

    teamone.setText(f.getTeamOne());
    teamtwo.setText(f.getTeamTwo());
    vs.setText("Vs");
    venue.setText(f.getVenue());
    date.setText(f.getDateInt());

    // NOTE: The correct way to compare strigs in Java is to use .equals(...)
    // Using == to compare strings will NOT work
    if(teamone.getText().toString().equals("Bangladesh"))
    {
        teamoneimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb);
    }
    else
    {
        teamoneimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        teamtwoimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no  problem with ur java file .Your problem is in fixture.xml file .In the nested Linearlayout(vertical)  you define "android:layout_weight" so your  "android:layout_height" should be set to "0dp" but you set it "match_parent "  .that's why your app is crashing every time try below code in your app & define "android:layout_height" "wrap_content/match_parent".This will solve your problem I'm sure